# Show status bar in node-webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nwjs

Is there a way in node-webkit to show the status bar - the strip at the bottom of the screen which displays the URL you are about to visit when hovering a link? Can it be set to a custom value like the olden days with `window.status`? I naturally thought this would be a value in package.json but I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this `command line switches` for node webkit

```
--disable-gpu --force-cpu-draw
```

but which version of NW did you use?